# Distributed vs clustered vs networked file system

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, distributed-computing

What is the differrence between a distributed file system, clustered file system and a network file system ?

Answer (score 3):

The usual classification is:

A *network file system* is

- a file system where clients can access data that is actually stored on other computers. Examples are AFS, SMB, NFS.
- the full name of the [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) network file system, initially developed by Sun Microsystems.
- a standardized protocol for compatible network file systems based on FS. Other vendors then Sun develop NFS servers, e.g. [NetApp](http://www.netapp.com/us/) or [EMC](http://www.emc.com/).

A *distribution file system* is another word for a network file system. It has the advantage that it is clearer that not necessarily NFS is meant.

A *cluster file system* is a file system where the data is distributed on multiple machines that appear to the clients as a single storage system (a cluster). Examples are [PanFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasas), [GPFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_General_Parallel_File_System), [Lustre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28file_system%29), and to make things more complicate [pNFS](http://www.pnfs.com/) (Parallel NFS).

Comment: I still don't get the difference between network vs clustered file system - if both provide a means to access data that is stored on different computers then why two different FS classifications ?

Comment: A network file system can be a various number of clients, accessing the data on *one (or more)* server computers. In a cluster file system, the data is stored at least *two* computers. However, the file system, which is distributed on at least two computers, appears to the clients as a single entity.

Comment: Again, this answer will be deleted in a week.